# Microphone voice playback not working?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, microphone

I'm trying to get mic playback with my Arctis 3 so I can hear my voice as I talk. I've been trying to follow these tutorials:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxW03z-uZBc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kj86Y5xvfBM

Basically, the videos say to:

1. Go to the Speaker Properties
2. Increase the slider for the microphone input (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK5zJ.png) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFAVH.png))

By doing so, this is supposed to allow me to hear my own voice with zero delay. But in my output device settings, there is no slider for "Microphone" and nothing happens if I bring the volume up for all sliders:

[image]

I have uninstalled and reinstalled my audio drivers from my motherboard manufacturer's website.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: No-one is going to watch 6 minutes of video to try to figure out what you did wrong. Please describe in words what you did, what the tutorials said you should do & what the results were. As is stands this question has no foundation if the videos are ever removed.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added information to my question to make that clear, @Tetsujin

Comment: There's also a program called VoiceMod that has a free version, and it (as well as having voice effects) also has a voice playback option and a noise reduction feature.

Comment: I am having the same problem trying to get the microphone from a USB webcam to play back through headphones plugged into a Realtek 3.5mm jack without the latency incurred by `Listen to this device`. If I open `Sound` → `Speakers` → `Properties` → `Levels` I have sliders for `Rear Pink In` and `Front Pink In`, among many others, but not the webcam's microphone. I suspect it just doesn't support bridging audio across sound devices like that; perhaps it can't be done in a no-latency way. For your case, your screenshot shows `Speakers`, but is that the right `Playback` device for your **headset**?

Answer (score 0):

May be This can resolve your issue If You are using Windows 10...

1. First Open Sound Control Panel by:

<kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>System</kbd> > <kbd>Sound</kbd> > <kbd>Sound Control Panel</kbd>

or <kbd>Right Click</kbd> on Speaker Icon on Taskbar and click <kbd>Sound</kbd>

2. Select your Microphone or Recording Device in <kbd>Recording</kbd> Tab.
3. Open **Properties** of your Input Device. eg. Microphone.
4. Select <kbd>Listen</kbd> Tab and **Check**  The Checkbox available With message:
   "Listen to this Device". and Select your Output Device for Sound Playback. for eg. Default Playback Device, Speakers or Headphones.

Accept The Answer and Give and Up-vote my Answer if this solve your issue.

Comment: So the problem with this method, as explained in the videos as well, is that there is a slight but very annoying delay when enabling mic playback through "Listen to this device", whereas the solution in the videos is another method that's supposed to not have any delay.